# Substring regex from characters to end of word

Tags: python, regex

I looking for a regex term that will capture a subset of a string beginning with a a certain sequence of characters (http in my case)up until a whitespace.

I am doing the problem in python, working over a list of strings and replacing the 'bad' substring with ''.

The difficulty stems from the characters not necessarily beginning the words within the substring. Example below, with bold being the part I am looking to capture:

"Pasforcément**httpwwwsudouestfr20101129lesyndromedeliledererevientdanslactualite2525391381php** merci **httpswwwgooglecomsilvous** "

Thank you

Comment: @ctwheels thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, klashxx's solution might be better than my original `http\w+(?= |$)` regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**findall**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> text = '''Pasforcémenthttpwwwsudouestfr20101129lesyndromedeliledererevientdanslactualite2525391381php merci httpswwwgooglecomsilvous '''
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'http\S+', text)
['httpwwwsudouestfr20101129lesyndromedeliledererevientdanslactualite2525391381php', 'httpswwwgooglecomsilvous']
```

For substitution (if memory not an issue):

```
>>> rep = re.compile(r'http\S+')
>>> rep.sub('', text)
```

Comment: I'm planning on applying a regex substitution to a list of 200 000 strings, to remove the http parts. Is compiling the regex, and then doing re.sub within a for-loop on each string the most efficient way?

Comment: @joelross what's the substitution?

Comment: @ctwheels just removing matched part so replacing with a space char ‘ ‘

Comment: @joelross do you really want to replace with a space considering the following character is a space? You can just replace with nothing (empty string)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
strings = [] #your list of strings goes here
import re
new_strings = [re.sub("https.*?php|https.*?$", '.', i) for i in strings]
```